# Table Per Locale

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table which has the following schema :  &  and I am mapping this to a Java class URLNameEntry which has two values URLName and creatorName. This class can be directly mapped to hibernate and there are no issues with that.

Now the problem i have different locales to deal with US, UK, DE etc. And I am planning to create a separate table for each of these locales Table_US, Table_UK, Table_DE and there will be more locales coming in the future. How would my java entity map to the different table based on the locale ?

I am thinking in this way : create a base abstract class URLNameEntry and implement USURLnameEntry, UKURLNameEntry... etc as subclasses and use Table per class strategy to solve this problem. Is this the correct approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a table per locale; this will introduce all sorts of headaches into your code, and the different entries are different kinds of things anyway. Use a locale column in a single table instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am designing a tool which should be useful for different websites(each website is in a different locale). For each site I require a set of tables like URLNameEntry, Audit etc. The reason for creating new tables for each website is to control the size of the tables otherwise if i keep everything in the same table it will blow up the system. Any suggestions on how to handle this ?

Comment: @Aditya How big is "blow up"? I'm very skeptical that a decent RDBMS can't handle as many rows as you're planning.